# C# VSTO add-in task sequence

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Within VSTO add-in for Outlook a button click fires 2 methods: first one performs simple actions on `MailItem Object` and runs quick, second one performs several other tasks requiring more computing time. I would like the second one to run in "background" so that the actions on `MailItem Object` quickly respond. Right now I could not figure out how to do that and the effects of actions on `MailItem Object` are only visible in Outlook once the 2 methods are completed.

```
public void ButtonAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    bool processed = ActionsOnMailItem();
    string output = OtherTasks(processed);
}

public static bool ActionsOnMailItem()
{
    Outlook.Selection selected = olApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    bool isEmailProcessed = false;
    try
    {
        foreach (Outlook.MailItem mailItem in selected)
        {
            mailItem.SaveAs(saveItemPath, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
        }
        isEmailProcessed = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        isEmailProcessed = false;
    }
    return isEmailProcessed;
}

public static string OtherTasks(bool isEmailProcessed)
{
    if (isEmailProcessed)
    {
        // Perform several tasks requiring computing time
        ...
    }
}
```

I have already tried with `async` methods but without success (no deadlock but no quick response for first method neither). Before I dig deeper into that I would like to know if this is the right path to follow or if there is a more straightforward way to do that.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to attempt to access COM objects from different threads from within a VSTO addin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must to be aware that accessing COM object from background thread involves marshaling which, in short, takes time. [Further reading...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshaling)

For your task you need to develop solution which uses `BackgroundWorker` class. [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) has two events that works on `MainThread` which are:

- ProgressChanged
- RunWorkerCompleted

Your `OtherTasks` method should use one of them to process result from background task.

For VSTO it is also important to use `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` before using BackgroundWorker class
For example:

```cs
// Forces BackgroundWorker to run ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events on VSTA_Main thread. It's important,
// because this thread manages Word COM objects. 
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff not using COM object
    worker.ReportProgress(0);
};
worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff on main thread (on COM objects)
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Works exactly as expected!

Answer (score 2):

As of Outlook 2016, a exception will be raised as soon as Outlook detects access on a thread other than the main Outlook thread. This really applies to the COM addins only as in out-of-proc (external) applications all calls will be marshalled to the main Outlook thread anyway, so multithreading in your app becomes a moot point.

You can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) on a secondary thread - read the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` property on the main thread (it returns `IMAPISession` object) and store it in a variable. On a secondary thread, call `MAPIInitialize` and use the `IMAPISesion` from the main thread - unlike OOM objects, it can be used from multiple threads. For languages other than C++ or Delphi, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects - it is a wrapper around Extended MAPI and can be used on secondary threads. Create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) on the secondary thread and set its MAPIOBJECT property to the value retrieved on the main thread from `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT`.

Comment: I have just tried tinamou's solution (using `BackgroundWorker` class) with Outlook 2016 and no exception is raised. Perhaps I must precise that the method called in background (`OtherTasks` in my question) does not use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application` to access `MailItem Object` but `win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")` called from an "external" application (as you mentioned it).

Comment: But that is Python used from an external app, not a COM addin, right?

Comment: Yes: the COM addin calls a first method accessing `MailItem Object` directly and a second one in background which runs an executable version of a Python script using `win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace‌​("MAPI")` to access `MailItem Object`.

Comment: And the calls from that executable will be marshaled to the main Outlook thread by the COM system.